# My map v3 simply refused to load

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, google-maps

Hello pals I cant figure out what is wrong with my map v3, it has refused to load. I used webview in android to load it but is not displaying the map. It only shows the button and textfields. Here is the code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Street View service</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
      #mode{
       height:5%;
       width:60%
       margin-left:0%;
       margin-right:0%;
       margin-top:5%;
       margin-bottom:0%
      }
      #autocomplete {
        font-size:11pt;
        align:center;
        width: 60%;
        margin-left:35%;
        margin-right:5%;
        margin-top:1%;
        margin-bottom:0%
      }
       #autocomplete1 {
        font-size:11pt;
        align:center;
        width: 60%;
        margin-left:35%;
        margin-right:5%;
        margin-top:1%;
        margin-bottom:0%
      }
      #from {
      margin-top:1%;
      margin-left:0%;
      margin-right:0%;
      margin-bottom:0%
      }
      #to {
      margin-top:1%;
      margin-left:0%;
      margin-right:0%;
      margin-bottom:0%
      }
      #locationField {
      margin-left:0%;
      margin-right:0%;
      margin-top:1%;
      margin-bottom:0%
      }
      #locationField1 {
      margin-left:0%;
      margin-right:0%;
      margin-top:1%;
      margin-bottom:0%
      }
      #button {
       align:center;
       margin-top:1%;
       margin-right:5%;
       margin-bottom:0%;
       margin-left:35%;
       width:60%;
       height:8%
      }
       #map-canvas {
       margin-top:1%;
       margin-right:0%;
       margin-bottom:0%;
       margin-left:0%;
       width: 100%;
       height: 30%
       }
    </style>

     <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
     <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>
    <script>

    var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var map;


   function initialize() {
   directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
   var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
   var mapOptions = {
    zoom:14,
    center: chicago,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    streetViewControl: false
      }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    }


    function searchDirection() {
  var start = document.getElementById("autocomplete").value;
  var end = document.getElementById("autocomplete1").value;
  var selectedMode = document.getElementById("mode").value;

  var request = {
    origin:start,
    destination:end,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.[selectedMode]

  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
    }
  });
}

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize();">
  <div id="text" style="width: 100%; height: 50%;">
  <div>
<strong>Direction By : </strong>
<select id="mode" onchange="calcRoute();">
  <option value="DRIVING">Driving</option>
  <option value="WALKING">Walking</option>
  <option value="BICYCLING">Bicycling</option>
  <option value="TRANSIT">Transit</option>
</select>
</div>

  <div id="locationField">
      <strong id="from">From : </strong>
      <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter Starting Point"
             onFocus="geolocate()" type="text"></input>
  </div>

  <div id="locationField1">
      <strong id="to">To : </strong>
      <input id="autocomplete1" placeholder="Enter Destination Point"
             onFocus="geolocate()" type="text"></input>
   </div>

   <input id="button" type="button" name="test" value="Search"  style=" font-size:12pt; background-color:#00FF00; color:#A9F5F2;" onclick="searchDirection()">

   </div>

   <div id="map-canvas"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is this a mistype:travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.[selectedMode] instead of travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode] ? the dot before []

Comment: Yes your right, I have corrected it, but the map still doesn't display in my screen. Do you have any idea what could be the cause?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvOpmo your code seems to work forme, but i am not sure that the % used to size and marge element is a good idea

Comment: thanks, I tested it again it worked. On the issue of using % for size, what do you recommend I use and what is wrong with %. Please note am not too familiar with html and javascript

Comment: % needs a parent with a size set via heigh or even width, only html and absolute/fixed positioned tag will use size of viewport as reference. if no reference from parent, then it turns to be : X% of null = nothing vertical margins and paddings uses parents width as reference.

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to version issue, Please make sure you are running it above Android 4.4.4 Kitkat because Google updated a lot of features regarding to webView in this particular version.

Apart from that:

Make sure you follow the steps in this documents owing to [webSetting](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setGeolocationEnabled(boolean)).

Also you have to implement the [WebChoromeClient][2].

And do not forget to add the required permission.

For code implementation, Please click on this [link][3].

[2]: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(java.lang.String, android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions.Callback)
[3]: https://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/06/embed-html-using-google-maps-javascript.html